# Does the conformal factor satisfy some equation independent of the vector field?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

Let $(M, g)$ be an $(n+1)$-dimensional (pseudo-)Riemannian manifold and for any
$X \in \mathcal{X}(M)$ define its deformation tensor by
\begin{align*}
{} ^{(X)}\pi_{ab} := (\mathcal{L}_X g)_{ab} = \nabla_a X_b + \nabla_b X_a.
\end{align*}
Fixing $X$ we may drop the superscript for brevity and compute
\begin{align*}
  \nabla_c \pi_{ab} &= \nabla_c \nabla_a X_b + {\color{red} \nabla_c \nabla_b X_a},
  \\
  \nabla_a \pi_{cb} &= \nabla_a \nabla_c X_b + \color{blue}\nabla_a \nabla_b X_c,
  \\
  \nabla_b \pi_{ac} &= {\color{blue} \nabla_b \nabla_a X_c} +
                      {\color{red} \nabla_b \nabla_c X_a},
\end{align*}
whereupon subtraction of the third equation from the sum of the first
two, and application of the identity $\nabla_{\mu} \nabla_{\nu}
X_{\lambda} - \nabla_{\nu} \nabla_{\mu} X_{\lambda} = R_{\mu \nu
  \lambda} {} ^{\rho} X_{\rho} $ gives
\begin{align*}
{} ^{(X)}\Gamma_{cab} &:= \nabla_c \pi_{ab} + \nabla_a \pi_{cb} - \nabla_b
               \pi_{ac}
  \\
             &=
  \nabla_c\nabla_a X_b + \nabla_a \nabla_c X_b + {\color{red}
                                                            R_{cba}{}
                                                            ^d X_d} +
                                                            {\color{blue}
                                                            R_{abc}{} ^dX_d}.
\end{align*}
Applying the algebraic Bianchi identity to the red term yields
\begin{align*}
{} ^{(X)}\Gamma_{cab} &= \nabla_c \nabla_a X_b + \nabla_a \nabla_c X_b -
  {\color{red} R_{acb}{} ^d X_d} - {\color{red} R_{bac}{} ^d X_d} +
  {\color{blue} R_{abc}{} ^d X_d}
  \\
  &= 2\nabla_c \nabla_a X_b -
2 R_{bac}{} ^d X_d
\end{align*}
Let us now assume
that $X$ is a conformal Killing vector field:
$$
  {} ^{(X)} \pi_{ab} = \Omega g_{ab}
$$
for some positive $\Omega \in C ^{\infty}(M)$. Under these conditions,
our previous identity shows that $X$ satisfies
\begin{align*}
\nabla_c \nabla_a X_b = R_{bac}{} ^d X_d + \frac{1}{2}(g_{ab} \nabla_c
  \Omega + g_{cb} \nabla_a \Omega - g_{ac} \nabla_b \Omega ).
\end{align*}
Tracing over $a$ and $c$ and using the fact that $g ^a{}_b = g ^{a
  \rho} g_{\rho b} = \delta ^a{}_b$ shows
\begin{align}
\square X_b &= R_{bd} X ^d + \frac{1}{2}(\delta ^a{}_b \nabla_a \Omega
              + \delta ^a{}_b \nabla_a \Omega - (n + 1) \nabla_b
              \Omega) \nonumber
  \\
  &= R_{bd} X ^d + \frac{1}{2}(2\nabla_b \Omega - (n + 1) \nabla_b
    \Omega) \nonumber
  \\
  &= R_{bd} X ^d - \frac{n-1}{2} \nabla_b \Omega. \tag{1}
\end{align}
Taking the covariant derivative with respect to $a$ and using the Riemann tensor as a commutator shows
\begin{align*}
\nabla_a \nabla_c \nabla ^c X_b &= \nabla_c \nabla_a \nabla ^c X_b +
                                  R_{ac b} {} ^d \nabla ^c X_d - R_{ac
                                  d}{} ^c \nabla ^d X_b
  \\
  &= \nabla ^c(  \nabla_c \nabla_a X_b + R_{ac b} {} ^d X_d) +
                                  R_{ac b} {} ^d \nabla ^c X_d - R_{ac
    d}{} ^c \nabla ^d X_b
  \\
                                &= \square \nabla_a X_b +
                                  \nabla ^c R_{ac b} {} ^d X_d +
                                  2R_{acb}{} ^d \nabla ^c X_d + R_{a
    d} \nabla ^d X_b.
\end{align*}
Applying the contracted Bianchi identity
to $\nabla ^c R_{acb d} = - \nabla ^c R_{cabd} = - \nabla_{d} R_{ab} +
\nabla_b R_{ad}$ we see that
\begin{align*}
\nabla_a \square X_b &= \square \nabla_a X_b + \nabla_b R_{ad} X ^d -
                       X ^d \nabla_d R_{ab} + 2R_{acb}{} ^d \nabla ^c
                       X_d  + R_{ad}\nabla
                       ^d X_b.
\end{align*}
Subtracting $\nabla_a (R_{bd} X ^d) = \nabla_a R_{bd} X ^d + R_{bd}
\nabla_a X ^d$ and recalling $(1)$ gives
\begin{align*}
- \frac{n-1}{2} \nabla_a \nabla_b \Omega &= \square \nabla_a X_b + \nabla_b R_{ad} X ^d -
                       X ^d \nabla_d R_{ab} + 2R_{acb}{} ^d \nabla ^c
                       X_d  + R_{ad}\nabla
                                           ^d X_b
  \\
  &- \nabla_a R_{bd} X ^d - R_{bd}
\nabla_a X ^d.
\end{align*}
Finally, from the symmetry of the Hessian we deduce
\begin{align*}
(1 - n) \nabla_a \nabla_b \Omega &= \square (\nabla_a X_b + \nabla_b X_a) - 2
                            X ^d \nabla_d R_{ab} + 2(R_{acb}{} ^d +
                            R_{bca}{} ^d)\nabla ^c X_d
  \\
  &+ R_{ad}\nabla
                            ^d X_b + R_{bd}\nabla ^d X_a - R_{bd}
    \nabla_aX ^d - R_{ad} \nabla_b X ^d
  \\
  &= \square \Omega g_{ab} - 2
                            X ^d \nabla_d R_{ab} + 2(R_{acb}{} ^d +
                            R_{bca}{} ^d)\nabla ^c X_d
  \\
  &+ R_{ad}\nabla
                            ^d X_b + R_{bd}\nabla ^d X_a - R_{bd}
    \nabla_aX ^d - R_{ad} \nabla_b X ^d. 
\end{align*}
If we were in flat space, this would reduce to the well known identity $(1-n) \nabla_a \nabla_b \Omega = \square \Omega g_{ab}$. However, on curved manifolds, I do not see a way to get rid of the curvature terms. I believe that $X^d \nabla_d R_{ab}$ should not be so hard to handle, since it looks like a Lie derivative of $R_{ab}$, but how does one reduce the remaining terms? Is clearing $X$ from the right hand side even possible?

**EDIT**
I have simplified the equation some more.
\begin{align}
(1 - n) \nabla_a \nabla_b \Omega &= \square (\nabla_a X_b + \nabla_b X_a) - 2
                            X ^d \nabla_d R_{ab} + 2(R_{acb}{} ^d +
                            R_{bca}{} ^d)\nabla ^c X_d \nonumber
  \\
  &+ {\color{blue} R_{ad}\nabla
                            ^d X_b} + {\color{red} R_{bd}\nabla ^d
    X_a} - {\color{red} R_{bd}
    \nabla_aX ^d} - {\color{blue} R_{ad} \nabla_b X ^d}. \tag{2}
\end{align}
Relabeling dummy indices and using the symmetries of the Riemann
tensor shows
\begin{align*}
(R_{acbd} + R_{bcad}) \nabla ^c X ^d &= R_{acbd} \nabla ^c X ^d +
                                       R_{bdac} \nabla ^d X ^c = R_{acbd} \nabla ^c X ^d +
                                       R_{acbd} \nabla ^d X ^c
  \\
  &= R_{acbd} \Omega g ^{cd} = - \Omega R_{ab}.
\end{align*}
Similarly, the blue terms in $(2)$ cancel:
\begin{align*}
R_a{} ^d \nabla _d X_b - R_a {} ^d \nabla_b X_d &= R_a{} ^d \nabla _d
                                                  X_b - R_a {} ^d
                                                  (\Omega g_{bd} -
                                                  \nabla_d X_b)
  \\
  &= R_a{} ^d \nabla _d
                                                  X_b - 
                                                  \Omega R_{ab} +
                                                  R_a {} ^d\nabla_d
    X_b
  \\
  &= \Omega R_a{} ^d g_{bd} - \Omega R_{ab} = 0,
\end{align*}
and by the same computation, the red terms will vanish as
well.

It turns out the term I thought would be the simplest is still presenting problems. My first idea would be to use the Lie derivative by recalling
\begin{align*}
  \mathcal{L}_X \text{Rc} (Y, Z) &= X (\text{Rc}(Y, Z)) - \text{Rc}([X, Y], Z) - \text{Rc}(Y, [X, Z])
  \\
  &= X (\text{Rc}(Y, Z)) - \text{Rc}(\nabla_X Y - \nabla_Y X, Z) - \text{Rc}(Y, \nabla_X Z -
    \nabla_Z X)
  \\
  &= X (\text{Rc}(Y, Z)) - \text{Rc}(\nabla_X Y, Z) + \text{Rc}(\nabla_Y X, Z) - \text{Rc}(Y, \nabla_X
    Z) +\text{Rc}(Y, 
    \nabla_Z X)
  \\
  &= \nabla_X \text{Rc}(Y, Z) + \text{Rc}(\nabla_Y X, Z) + \text{Rc}(Y, \nabla_Z X)
\end{align*}
Contracting Konstant's formula with $Z ^c$ and $Y ^a$ gives
\begin{align*}
(\nabla ^2 X)(Y, Z) &= Z ^c Y ^a\nabla_c \nabla_a X ^b = Z ^c Y ^a X ^d
                      R ^b{}_{acd} + Z ^c Y ^a F_{ac}{}^b (\Omega)
  \\
  &= Z ^c Y ^a X ^d
    R_{cd}{} ^b{}_a + Z ^c Y ^a F_{ac}{}^b (\Omega)
  \\
  &= R(Z, X)Y + F(Y, Z, \Omega)
\end{align*}
Recall now that $(\nabla ^2 X)(Y, Z) = \nabla_Z(\nabla X)(Y) =
\nabla_Z \nabla_Y X - \nabla_{\nabla_Z Y} X$ so that expanding $R(Z,
X)Y$ yields
\begin{align*}
\nabla_Z \nabla_YX - \nabla_{\nabla_Z Y} X &= \nabla_Z \nabla_X Y -
                                             \nabla_X \nabla_Z Y -
                                             \nabla_{[Z, X]} Y + F(Y,
                                             Z, \Omega). 
\end{align*}
Subtracting $\nabla_Z \nabla_Y X$ and adding $\nabla_X \nabla_Z Y$ to
both sides simplifies to
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}_X (\nabla_Z Y) &= [X,\nabla_Z Y] = \nabla_X \nabla_Z Y -
                             \nabla_{\nabla_Z Y} X
  \\
  &= \nabla_Z \nabla_X Y -
    \nabla_Z \nabla_Y X + \nabla_{[X, Z]} Y + F(Y, Z, \Omega)
  \\
  &= \nabla_Z
    [X, Y] + \nabla_{[X, Z]} Y + F(Y, Z, \Omega)
  \\
  &= \nabla_Z (
  \mathcal{L}_XY) + \nabla_{\mathcal{L}_XZ} Y + F(Y, Z, \Omega).
\end{align*}
Putting $Y \mapsto \nabla_Y W$ gives
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}_X(\nabla_Z \nabla_Y W)   &= \nabla_Z (
  \mathcal{L}_X \nabla_Y W) + \nabla_{\mathcal{L}_XZ} \nabla_Y W +
                                       F(\nabla_Y W, Z, \Omega)
  \\
  &= \nabla_Z ( \nabla_Y (
  \mathcal{L}_X W) + \nabla_{\mathcal{L}_X Y} W + F(W, Y, \Omega)) + \nabla_{\mathcal{L}_XZ} \nabla_Y W +
    F(\nabla_Y W, Z, \Omega)
  \\
  &= \nabla_Z  \nabla_Y (
  \mathcal{L}_X W) +  \nabla_Z  \nabla_{\mathcal{L}_X Y} W  +
    \nabla_{\mathcal{L}_XZ} \nabla_Y W +  \nabla_Z F(W, Y, \Omega)+
    F(\nabla_Y W, Z, \Omega).
\end{align*}
Swapping $Y$ and $Z$ and subtracting:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}_X(R(Z, Y) W) &= {\color{purple} \nabla_Z  \nabla_Y (
  \mathcal{L}_X W)} + {\color{red}  \nabla_Z  \nabla_{\mathcal{L}_X Y} W } +
                           {\color{blue} 
    \nabla_{\mathcal{L}_XZ} \nabla_Y W} +  \nabla_Z F(W, Y, \Omega)+
                           F(\nabla_Y W, Z, \Omega)
  \\
  &- {\color{purple} \nabla_Y  \nabla_Z (
  \mathcal{L}_X W) }- {\color{blue} \nabla_Y  \nabla_{\mathcal{L}_X Z}
    W}  -{\color{red}     \nabla_{\mathcal{L}_XY} \nabla_Z W}- \nabla_Y F(W, Z, \Omega)-
    F(\nabla_Z W, Y, \Omega)
  \\
  &- {\color{purple} \nabla_{[Z, Y]} (
    \mathcal{L}_XW)} - \nabla_{[X, [Z, Y]]} W - F(W, [Z, Y], \Omega)
  \\
  &= {\color{purple} R(Z, Y) \mathcal{L}_X W} + {\color{blue}
    R(\mathcal{L}_X Z, Y) W} + {\color{red} R(Z, \mathcal{L}_X Y)W} +
    \mathbf {F}(Y ,Z, W, \Omega)
\end{align*}
where we used the Jacobi identity
$$
  \mathcal{L}_X [Z, Y] = [X, [Z, Y]]
= - [Y, [X, Z]] - [Z, [Y, X]] = [ \mathcal{L}_X Z, Y] + [Z,
\mathcal{L}_X Y ]
$$
to simplify the blue and red terms with
$\nabla_{\mathcal{L}_X [Z, Y]}W$. Sending the first three terms to the
left hand side and using the formula for the Lie derivative of a
tensor, we see that
\begin{align*}
[\mathcal{L}_X R(Z, Y)] W = \mathbf {F}(Y ,Z, W, \Omega) &:= \nabla_Z F(W, Y, \Omega) + F(\nabla_Y W,
                            Z, \Omega) - \nabla_Y F(W, Z, \Omega)
  \\
  &-
                            F(\nabla_Z W, Y, \Omega)
- F(W, [Z, Y], \Omega).
\end{align*}
Hence, all I need to do is express
$$
\text{Rc}(\nabla_Y X, Z) + \text{Rc}(Y, \nabla_Z X)
$$
in an $X$-independent way.

**Question**

If $X$ is a conformal vector field $\nabla_a X_b + \nabla_b X_a = \Omega g_{ab}$ is it possible to generalize the equation
$$
(n-1) \nabla_a\nabla_b \Omega + \square \Omega g_{ab} = 0
$$
(i.e. an equation for $\Omega$ independent of $X$) to manifolds? According to the calculations above, it seems it would suffice to express $\text{Rc}(\nabla_Y X, Y)$ in an $X$-independent way.

Comment: It's quite hard to read your post to find the relevant questions; you might want to consider doing something to emphasize where your question is. Some possibilities I've seen in other posts include bolding the question itself, putting it in its own box, using horizontal lines to set off post-question remarks, or rearranging the post so that the question is in an easier location to find (such as the end).

Comment: @user44191 I have added the question to the end of my post.